# MT5 python not returning updated data

Tags: python, metatrader5

MT5 is not returning data for the most recent index

```
import MetaTrader5 as mt5
mt5.initialize()
import pandas as pd

instrument = mt5.copy_rates_from_pos('BTCUSD',mt5.TIMEFRAME_H1,0,20)
instrument = pd.DataFrame(instrument)
instrument['time'] = pd.to_datetime(instrument['time'], unit = 's')
instrument = instrument.set_index(['time'])
```

When I run this code every hour, it always returns the previous bar as the last index (instead of the most recent bar). It should return the most recent bar since the initial bar index is set to 0.

Example of data not being updated:

```
In()
instrument['open'].tail(5)

Out()
2022-10-29 11:00:00    20767.92
2022-10-29 12:00:00    20917.95
2022-10-29 13:00:00    20945.44
2022-10-29 14:00:00    20763.64
2022-10-29 15:00:00    20690.48
```

If I run the same code 10 seconds later, it returns the correct information (most recent bar as the last index).

Correct (updated) data:

```
In()
instrument['open'].tail(5)

Out()
2022-10-29 12:00:00    20917.95
2022-10-29 13:00:00    20945.44
2022-10-29 14:00:00    20763.64
2022-10-29 15:00:00    20690.48
2022-10-29 16:00:00    20756.35
```

So from what I can tell the terminal has not updated the information when - mt5.copy_rates_from_pos - is executed.

How can I force the terminal to download and update the data before?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

you can actually update the close price every second if you want to. You have to run it with datetime otherwise you wont return the updated date and time from mt5. and run your function to pull the data from inside loop.

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
import MetaTrader5 as mt
import pandas as pd

q = 0
while q < 1:
    dt = datetime.now()
    mt = dt.strftime( '%H:%M:%S' )
    if dt.second > dt.second - 1:
        pull your data here
        print output
    time.sleep( 1 )
```

remember only the close price will update every second, unless new highs or lows are made within the bar interval, then they will update as well. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get the latest 1-hour bar data for several forex pairs using MetaTrader5 and copy_rates_from_pos. Some pairs returned the latest data, some pairs returned data except the latest hour. I poked around and found a solution. I am not sure if it is the best solution, but it seems to work.

Basically copy_rates_from_pos fetches the data that is already in your locally running MetaTrader 5. In order to have my MetaTrade 5 load the data as soon as possible, I needed to open the chart for the currency pairs that I was interested in. If I don't open the chart for a pair, MetaTrade 5 doesn't fetch the data in a timely fashion. It kind of makes sense.